Issue with TPC hierarchy and relations in EF Core 8 + PostgreSQL
I have a problem when trying to use TPC hierarchy mapping in EF Core 8, where I get InvalidCastExceptions.
What I wanted to do is have a BaseAuditedEntity class for most models in my app (only except for Identity models), so that I could use it for an unrelated feature: TierList entity that has many TierListItems, and each TierListItem relates to a BaseAuditedEntity entity in the app, such as a Circle (music group) or ArrangementSong.
The (simplified) models:
public class Circle : BaseAuditedEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<ArrangementSong> ArrangementSongs { get; set; }
}

public class ArrangementSong : BaseAuditedEntity
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public int CircleId { get; set; }
    public Circle Circle { get; set; }

    public List<OfficialSong> OfficialSongs { get; set; }
    public List<OfficialSongArrangementSong> OfficialSongArrangementSongs { get; set; }
}

public class OfficialSong : BaseAuditedEntity
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public required List<ArrangementSong> ArrangementSongs { get; set; }
    public required List<OfficialSongArrangementSong> OfficialSongArrangementSongs { get; set; }
}

public class TierListItem : BaseEntity
{
    public int TierListTierId { get; set; }
    public TierListTier TierListTier { get; set; } = default!;

    public int SourceId { get; set; }
    public BaseAuditedEntity Source { get; set; }
}

public abstract class BaseAuditedEntity : BaseEntity
{
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string CreatedByUserName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public DateTime? UpdatedOn { get; set; }
    public string? UpdatedByUserName { get; set; }
}

public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

The base classes configuration:
        modelBuilder.Entity<BaseEntity>()
            .UseTpcMappingStrategy();


        modelBuilder.Entity<Circle>()
            .HasMany(c => c.ArrangementSongs)
            .WithOne(a => a.Circle)
            .IsRequired();

A simple query could be like this:
var arrangementSongs_Res = await _context.ArrangementSongs
    .Include(a => a.Circle)
    .Include(a => a.OfficialSongs)
    .Select(a => new ArrangementSongResponse(a)
    {
        CircleName = a.Circle.Name,
        OfficialSongTitles = a.OfficialSongs.Select(os => os.Title).ToList(),
    })
    .ToListAsync();

But when running, I get this exception (it doesn't happen if I remove the .Include(a => a.Circle) line):
[16:13:14 INFOR] Executed DbCommand (25ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT a.id, a.created_by_user_name, a.created_on, a.updated_by_user_name, a.updated_on, a.circle_id, a.status, a.title, a.title_japanese, a.title_romaji, a.url, c.id, c.created_by_user_name, c.created_on, c.updated_by_user_name, c.updated_on, c.name, c.status, t.id, t.arrangement_song_id, t.official_song_id, t.id0, t.created_by_user_name, t.created_on, t.updated_by_user_name, t.updated_on, t.context, t.game_id, t.title, t0.title, t0.id, t0.id0
FROM arrangement_songs AS a
INNER JOIN circles AS c ON a.circle_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT o.id, o.arrangement_song_id, o.official_song_id, o0.id AS id0, o0.created_by_user_name, o0.created_on, o0.updated_by_user_name, o0.updated_on, o0.context, o0.game_id, o0.title
    FROM official_song_arrangement_song AS o
    INNER JOIN official_songs AS o0 ON o.official_song_id = o0.id
) AS t ON a.id = t.arrangement_song_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT o2.title, o1.id, o2.id AS id0, o1.arrangement_song_id
    FROM official_song_arrangement_song AS o1
    INNER JOIN official_songs AS o2 ON o1.official_song_id = o2.id
) AS t0 ON a.id = t0.arrangement_song_id
ORDER BY a.id, c.id, t.id, t.id0, t0.id
[16:13:14 ERROR] An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'Touhou_Songs.Data.AppDbContext'.
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Touhou_Songs.App.Unofficial.Songs.ArrangementSong' to type 'Touhou_Songs.App.Unofficial.Circles.Circle'.
   at lambda_method70(Closure, QueryContext, DbDataReader, ResultContext, SingleQueryResultCoordinator)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Touhou_Songs.App.Unofficial.Songs.ArrangementSong' to type 'Touhou_Songs.App.Unofficial.Circles.Circle'.
   at lambda_method70(Closure, QueryContext, DbDataReader, ResultContext, SingleQueryResultCoordinator)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
[16:13:14 INFOR] Executed action Touhou_Songs.App.Unofficial.ArrangementSongs.ArrangementSongsController.GetArrangementSongs (Touhou_Songs) in 2101.1069ms
[16:13:14 INFOR] Executed endpoint 'Touhou_Songs.App.Unofficial.ArrangementSongs.ArrangementSongsController.GetArrangementSongs (Touhou_Songs)'
[16:13:15 ERROR] HTTP GET /api/ArrangementSongs responded 500 in 2264.5217 ms
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Touhou_Songs.App.Unofficial.Songs.ArrangementSong' to type 'Touhou_Songs.App.Unofficial.Circles.Circle'.
   at lambda_method70(Closure, QueryContext, DbDataReader, ResultContext, SingleQueryResultCoordinator)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Touhou_Songs.App.Unofficial.ArrangementSongs.Features.GetArrangementSongsHandler.Handle(GetArrangementSongsQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\Dev\SSD Projects\Main\Touhou_Songs\API\Server\App\Unofficial\ArrangementSongs\Features\GetArrangementSongs.cs:line 41
   at Touhou_Songs.App.Unofficial.ArrangementSongs.ArrangementSongsController.GetArrangementSongs(GetArrangementSongsQuery query) in D:\Dev\SSD Projects\Main\Touhou_Songs\API\Server\App\Unofficial\ArrangementSongs\ArrangementSongsController.cs:line 19
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|7_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Serilog.AspNetCore.RequestLoggingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
[16:13:15 ERROR] An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Touhou_Songs.App.Unofficial.Songs.ArrangementSong' to type 'Touhou_Songs.App.Unofficial.Circles.Circle'.
   at lambda_method70(Closure, QueryContext, DbDataReader, ResultContext, SingleQueryResultCoordinator)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Touhou_Songs.App.Unofficial.ArrangementSongs.Features.GetArrangementSongsHandler.Handle(GetArrangementSongsQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\Dev\SSD Projects\Main\Touhou_Songs\API\Server\App\Unofficial\ArrangementSongs\Features\GetArrangementSongs.cs:line 41
   at Touhou_Songs.App.Unofficial.ArrangementSongs.ArrangementSongsController.GetArrangementSongs(GetArrangementSongsQuery query) in D:\Dev\SSD Projects\Main\Touhou_Songs\API\Server\App\Unofficial\ArrangementSongs\ArrangementSongsController.cs:line 19
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|7_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Serilog.AspNetCore.RequestLoggingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)
[16:13:15 INFOR] Request finished HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:5000/api/ArrangementSongs - 500 null text/plain; charset=utf-8 2424.9688ms

I'm guessing that this is a problem with BaseEntity rows in the DB. There is no BaseEntity table because it's TPC, but after a migration I made to update the models from standalone Ids to using a base class, then I see that they use a common sequence. However, the existing Ids are unchanged, so there are many rows that share the same Ids. But I'm not sure if this is the cause, or how to fix this.
Any help with this issue of mine is greatly appreciated!

@Dai That's not the issue. If I rewrite the query as:
await _context.ArrangementSongs.Include(a => a.OfficialSongs).Select(a => new ArrangementSongResponse(a) { CircleName = "asdsafas", OfficialSongTitles = a.OfficialSongs.Select(os => os.Title).ToList(), }).ToListAsync();
...then it works as normal, notice that I've removed the Include for a.Circle. Plus, these queries worked fine before I tried to make every model inherit from a base class (so each model would have its own public int Id { get; set; } rather than in a base class)

Interesting. Thank you for letting me know (I haven't used EFC8 yet).

how does this work .Include(a => a.OfficialSongs) I don't see OfficialSongs on ArrangementSong in the code you provided

Why this query needs includes? Select should ignore them.

@IvanPetrov Sorry, I was simplifying the code and accidentally also removed part of the model. ArrangementSong has public List<OfficialSong> OfficialSongs { get; set; }   public List<OfficialSongArrangementSong> OfficialSongArrangementSongs { get; set; } as well
@SvyatoslavDanyliv I didn't know that, thanks! Although I will still need the Include for other queries that return the entities themselves and not a mapped response.

@N.T.Dang thanks, can you update the question with the info...maybe OfficialSong definition as well.

@IvanPetrov I've included those models in the post. Although there are still some more entity models, but I think they're irrelevant to the issue so I've left them out for clarity

@N.T.Dang I am trying to make sense of Unable to cast object of type 'Touhou_Songs.App.Unofficial.Songs.ArrangementSong' to type 'Touhou_Songs.App.Unofficial.Circles.Circle'.  why is it attempting the cast and where is the question.

@IvanPetrov That's my problem too, I don't know why it's casting from those 2 types when they are unrelated. The only possible reasoning I could think of is that they both inherit BaseAuditedEntity, and in the DB they have existing records with the same Ids (because the data existed before I made them inherit from BaseAuditedEntity
